# Not enough permissions to access field. How to access other profile fields from LinkedIn API?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to get profile field sections like location, certificate, education, etc of the logged in user.
I am following the Oauth-flow. The permissions available for me are: `r_basicprofile, w_member_social, r_organization_social, r_liteprofile`. I am trying to use `/v2/me` endpoint but it says permission denied after using this in postman

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,firstName,profilePicture,course,certificate`.

Am I doing this wrong or are there no permissions for me to access it?

I read through the documentation, applied for other products like `Share on LinkedIn, Community Management API` in dashboard and got access to it but still it doesn't work

I tried using `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,profilePicture,course,certificate)` and it still returns default field projections.